# Privacy Concerns When Displaying PDFs via Google Docs API

Tags: security, pdf, google-docs-api, pdf.js, privacy

I am currently using pdfjs to render pdfs that I am streaming from an S3 bucket with a temporary signed url.

I am trying to keep these files private. An account is required to view them.

I am considering using the Google Docs API to view pdfs because it is super easy and honestly just looks a lot better than my attempt at creating a viewer with PDFJS.

Can anyone explain what happens when I use a temporary signed url to view a document with google? I can imagine that there would be a copy made on a google server somewhere, but I don't see how anyone could ever gain access to that specific document in a public way.

In short, I want to use a shortcut and I need someone to scare me out of it.

The endpoint is docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=

---

I have 'successfully' implemented both solutions but I would prefer to outsource this functionality IF it is not unreasonably insecure.